# Why does recursive/nested `setTimeout` does not stop execution without an `else` statement?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, scheduling

I am learning to use recursive `setTimeout` function.

My task is to create a function that takes 2 number arguments, `from` and `to` and prints each number in between to the console, one at the time with the delay of 1 second in between.

My question is, why function `printNumbers1` does not stop execution after printing number `4` to the console? The assumption is that the `timerID` is incorrect, but I do not understand why.

```js
const DELAY = 1000;

const printNumbers1 = (from, to) => {
  let counter = from;
  let timerID = setTimeout(function run() {
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;

    if (counter > to) clearTimeout(timerID);

    // the function not stop the invocation without the `else` statement
    timerID = setTimeout(run, DELAY);
  }, DELAY)
}

const printNumbers2 = (from, to) => {
  let counter = from;
  let timerID = setTimeout(function run() {
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;
    if (counter > to) clearTimeout(timerID);
    else {
      timerID = setTimeout(run, DELAY);
    }
  }, DELAY)
}

printNumbers1(1, 4); // continues to execute after 4th invocation
printNumbers2(1, 4); // stops execution after 4th invocation
```

Comment: In `printNumbers1` you just clear the timer, and set a new timer without actually conditioning it. You don't need to clear a timeout when it fires, if you do `if (counter < to) timerID = setTimeout(run, DELAY);` then you can run the code without the `else` part.

Comment: In other words, the `timerID` you do clear is the one representing the one callback that is being executed, i.e it's already too late to clear it.

Comment: `if(counter > to) clearTimeout(timerID);` is clearing a no longer existing timerID. If you change the first code to use setInterval, then it will work too

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the first code block, the execution continues, setTimeout is called again and it sets timerID another value.

After `counter > to` condition is satisfied, you need to stop the execution or prevent the next line (which calls setTimeout again) to be executed. That's why the second code block is correct.

When you call clearTimeout, it just clears the previously set timer but does not stop the execution of the rest of the code block (which includes calling another setTimeout in the next code line).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarifications @Zafer, @Teemu.

Now, it's clear that I should have either stopped the execution in my `if` statement like this:

```js
const printNumbers1 = (from, to) => {
  let counter = from;
  let timerID = setTimeout(function run(){
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;

    if(counter > to) return;    
    timerID = setTimeout(run, DELAY);
  }, DELAY)
}
```

or, as @Teemu suggested, invoke the recursive function only if the condition is satisfied like this:

```js
const printNumbers1 = (from, to) => {
  let counter = from;
  let timerID = setTimeout(function run(){
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;
    
    if(counter <= to) timerID = setTimeout(run, DELAY);
  }, DELAY)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `clearTimeout(timerID);` at all. It does nothing, the timeout has already occured.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, makes sense. Thanks. Will edit now.